# Why does my terminal app not open on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line

So basically, my terminal app on Ubuntu 22.04 GUI does not open. When i try to open it, it shows "Terminal" + a loading sign on the top of the screen for a few seconds until it stops.

I have no clue what can cause this.

Comment: You did something with python on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, try to open and close, in the header it shows "bin/false" or "None" and in the bottom line "none 80x24"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1265221)